# Wordpress select statement with order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress query which works fine without the order by, however when i add it in, it returns nothing.

```
 public function getUsers(){

    global $wpdb; 

    return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users ORDER BY $wpdb->con_created_at ASC", OBJECT );

}
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong? Cheers

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: So whats the problem then?

Comment: When i use a standard query i get the results. I want to order those results by date_created. However when i add the order by the results do not appear anymore. Which suggests i have the syntax wrong..?

Comment: There is probably somewhere a log on the serverside

Comment: Are you sure that $wpdb->con_created_at holds the thing you think should hold?

Comment: `ORDER BY con_created_at` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can't get value of object property in quotes like this. You are getting `prefix` property value correctly. Get `con_created_at` same way.

```
return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users ORDER BY {$wpdb->con_created_at} ASC", OBJECT );
```

or use string concatenation

```
return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users ORDER BY ".$wpdb->con_created_at." ASC", OBJECT );
```

But I think `$wpdb` dosen't have `con_created_at`. This is just field name. So

```
return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users ORDER BY con_created_at ASC", OBJECT );
```

should be correct.

For more info visit [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).